# How to create a Chart Tooltip with the Date (DateTime Format)

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime, charts, data-visualization

I can't get a hint in the right format

```
foreach (RootObject o in myRootObjects)
{ 
    seriesTemperatur.Points.AddXY(DateTime.Parse(o.datum), o.temp);               
    seriesPressure.Points.AddXY(DateTime.Parse(o.datum),  o.pressure);
}
```

__

```
private void chart2_GetToolTipText(object sender, ToolTipEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.HitTestResult.ChartElementType)
    {
        case ChartElementType.DataPoint:
            var dataPoint = e.HitTestResult.Series.Points[e.HitTestResult.PointIndex];
            e.Text = string.Format("Temperatur C:\t{1}\nData: {0}", dataPoint.XValue, dataPoint.YValues[0]);
            break;
    }
}
```

As a Date in dataPoint.XValue i get

```
dataPoint {{X=43459,6591203704, Y=3,19}},
```

But i need X="2018-11-22 HH:mm".

```
var dataPoint = e.HitTestResult.Series.Points[e.HitTestResult.PointIndex];
e.Text = string.Format("Temperatur C:\t{1}\nData: {0}", dataPoint.XValue, dataPoint.YValues[0]);
```

i get:

> dataPoint  {{X=43459,6591203704, Y=3,19}}            System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPoint

AxisLabel is empty

```
    AxisLabel   ""  string
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your values were added as `DateTime` and you want to format them for some other purpose than a `Label` (which ought to be able to use its `Format` string) you will need to convert them. The same applies if you want to do other processing like comparisons or filters etc..

In fact all the chart values you add, **always** get converted to `double`. So you need to use the conversion function [FromOADate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.fromoadate?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
var dataPoint = e.HitTestResult.Series.Points[e.HitTestResult.PointIndex];
DateTime dtx = DateTime.FromOADate(dataPoint.XValue);
e.Text = string.Format("Temperatur C:\t{1}\nData: {0}", dtx, dataPoint.YValues[0]);
```

Answer (score 4):

You should specify format of your X axis like this

```
chart.seriesTemperatur.XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm";
```

Comment: Use your series instead of Series[0]. I suppose it will be seriesTemperatur in your case

Comment: He is not talking about the axis labels but a tooltip.

Answer (score -1):

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a02729eb-46d9-4649-ad49-6a7ba581b485/datetime-in-tooltip?forum=MSWinWebChart

```
c.Series[i - 1].XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
```

Comment: 'chartTemperatur.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm";
                chartTemperatur.Series[0].XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
                chartTemperatur.Series[0].ToolTip = "#VALY{F}\n#VALX{yyyy-mm-dd}";'           it all didn't work